# Dúvida com relacionamento n-n typeORM

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Olá.

estou em um projeto ondes temos um relacionamento entre permissoes e usuários. ficando com a entidade de permissions e users. criamos mais uma entidade da tabela associativa q faz a ligação entre users e permission.

ficando assim. entidade: users, permissions, e userPermissions.

sei q o typeORM faz a criação dessa tabela associativa porém tive que adicionar alguns campos a mais na tabela e por isso fiz ela manual.

sendo assim a userPermissions recebe a chave estrangeira das outras tabelas e adicionei mais 1 campo.

minha consulta ta ficando assim:
UserService:

```
    async findUserPermission(idUser: number) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: idUser },   
    });

    const permission = await this.userPermissionService.getPermissionByUser(idUser);
      
    return UserMap.toDto(user, permission);
```

isso me atende tranquilo quando tenho somente 1 retorno. porém quando quero buscar vários usuários e listar suas permissions não sei como fazer pq a consulta da permission tem q ser feita "ao msm tempo" q a consulta do usuário

```
async findAll(){
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  where: { active: true },
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
});
```

aqui agora teria q fazer a consulta das permissions de acordo com cada usuário

```
const result = user.map((userMap) => {
  const permission = userMap.permission.map(() => {
    const seiLa = this.userPermissionService.getPermissionByUser(user.id)
      
    console.log(`user.id: ${user.id}, \n`);
    console.log('Permission: ', seiLa);
  });
  console.log('Permission: ', JSON.stringify(permission));
});

console.log('RESULT: ', JSON.stringify(result));

return ;
```

}

assim. nos console.log da como promisse pendente e n aceita usar await dentro do map. aqui já fiz várias mudanças tentando um monte de coisa e n consegui tratar.

quando passo a propriedade RELATIONS me retorna os dados da tabela userPermission pq é com ela q existe o relacionamento porém preciso passar os dados da permission junto para o front.

se alguém poder me ajudar, falar oq pode ser mudado ou uma melhor implementação. se tem como deixar o typeORM tratar esse relacionamento n-n direto e msm assim passar uma propriedade a mais para a tabela associativa

Answer (score 1):

Opa, amigo!

O erro provavelmente está aqui:

```
const result = user.map((userMap) => {
    ...
}
```

Quando você deseja utilizar um callback assíncrono num loop qualquer, independente de qual for, você deve fazer duas coisas:

1° - Indicar que o método é assíncrono. É simples, apenas faça:

```
user.map(async (userMap) => {
   ...
}
```

2° - Já que agora o map retornará Promises de um objeto você deve utilizar o método `Promise.all`, assim sendo, seu código ficará assim:

```
const users = await Promise.all(user.map(async (userMap) => {
   ...
})
```

Assim você poderá tranquilamente colocar os await dentro do map.

E você deverá fazer a mesma coisa no map aninhado que está no seu código.

Alguns adendos que eu gostaria de fazer, se eu entendi bem sua pergunta você quer apenas pegar as relations dos usuários, nesse caso fazer um `join` simples, para fazer isso utilizando o typeorm você terá apenas que fazer o seguinte:

```
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  where: { active: true },
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
  relations: [ "permission" ]/* aqui é um array de strings, apenas ponha o nome das relations que você deseja pegar (imaginando que seja permission o nome da sua relação) */
});
```

Porém, para isso funcionar sua entidade deve está configurada corretamente, um exemplo seria:

```
@Entity("users") 
class User {
   @Column()
   email: string;

   @OneToOne(() => Permission /* O tipo do objeto da relação */)
   @JoinColumn()
   permission: Permission;
}
```

Ou seja, o find irá retornar todos os usuários juntamente com suas respectivas `relations` do tipo `permission`. Se você tiver outras relations na sua tabela basta colocar seus nomes no array do `relations`, assim:

```
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  where: { active: true },
  skip: 0,
  take: 10,
  relations: [ "permission", "relation1", "relation2", "relation3" ]
});
```

Lembrando que nesse caso o typeorm irá criar a tabela de join automaticamente.

Outra coisa, você realmente precisa colocar mais uma coluna na tabela de Join?

Sei que a pergunta faz um tempo, mas estou aberto a mais perguntas. Espero ter ajudado!